# sqlite3 connector in python

Tags: python, numpy, sqlite

This doesn't work: I don't get any element.

k0 is float numpy, dk is int:

```
(k0, dk)
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'int'>)
(20.083143869749225, 6)
```

-

```
get_close_rods = "select xmid, ymid, angle from datos where  experiment_id=? "
get_close_rods+= "and file_id=? and ymid between ? and ? and xmid between ? and ? and angle between ? and ? "
get_close_rods+= "and major/minor between ? and ? order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle" 
#get_close_rods+= "order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle"

args = (str(experiment_id_), str(file_ids[index+1]), str(pos0[1]-dd),
            str(pos0[1]+dd), str(pos0[0]-dd), str(pos0[0]+dd),
            str(angle-dangle), str(angle+dangle), str(k0-dk), str(k0+dk),
            str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[1]), str(pos0[1]))

cursor2.execute(get_close_rods, args)
```

**str(k0-dk), str(k0+dk)**

It doesn't work either:

```
get_close_rods = "select xmid, ymid, angle, from datos where  experiment_id=? "
get_close_rods+= "and file_id=? and ymid between ? and ? and xmid between ? and ? and angle between ? and ? "
get_close_rods+= "and major/minor between ? and ? order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle" 
#get_close_rods+= "order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle"

args = (str(experiment_id_), str(file_ids[index+1]), str(pos0[1]-dd),
            str(pos0[1]+dd), str(pos0[0]-dd), str(pos0[0]+dd),
            str(angle-dangle), str(angle+dangle), str(15), str(25),
            str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[1]), str(pos0[1]))

cursor2.execute(get_close_rods, args)
```

**str(15), str(25)**

Doesn't work either if I put **str(float(15)), str(float(25))**.

It doesn't show any error when I use that query.

But this works:

```
get_close_rods = "select xmid, ymid, angle, from datos where  experiment_id=? "
get_close_rods+= "and file_id=? and ymid between ? and ? and xmid between ? and ? and angle between ? and ? "
#get_close_rods+= "and major/minor between ? and ? order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle" 
#get_close_rods+= "order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle"
get_close_rods+= "and major/minor between 15 and 25 order by ((xmid-?)*(xmid-?)+(ymid-?)*(ymid-?))*angle"

args = (str(experiment_id_), str(file_ids[index+1]), str(pos0[1]-dd),
            str(pos0[1]+dd), str(pos0[0]-dd), str(pos0[0]+dd),
            str(angle-dangle), str(angle+dangle), #str(15), str(25),
            str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[0]), str(pos0[1]), str(pos0[1]))

cursor2.execute(get_close_rods, args)
```

**#str(15), str(25)**

Comment: with *args I get: TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (15 given)

Comment: nope: 14 question marks, 14 args

Answer (score 0):

Using directly values fixed it:

```
args = (..., 15, 25, ...)
```

or:

```
args = (..., k0-dk, k0+dk, ...)
```